# Open page in window at a specific position

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Beside the general Help page I am planning to add a help button across the website pointing to specific sections of the help page. i.e, the button "Help" in customer page should open a window and display the "help - customer" section of the help page.
This is how I open the window on help click:

```
function openHelpCustomers() {
                var width = "300px";
                var height = "450px";
                var left = "900px";
                var top = "150px";
                radopen("help.aspx", "RadWindow1", width, height, left, top);
            }
```

The question is how can I open the page "help.aspx" in the window at the needed section/line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using fragment identifiers maybe?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Comment: Thanks. For other people references: I made a div with id="customers" in the help page and the call url became help.aspx#customers.